# Customizing a UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I'd like to make customizations to a UIImagePickerController that allow the user to select a photo from one of their photo albums. I was wondering if the following is possible and if so, how it's accomplished:

1) Change the color of the navigation bar on the "Photo Albums" view and the view that appears after a photo album is selected.

2) Edit the buttons and their actions on both of the views.

3) Add a toolbar to the bottom of both image picker views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I've found a solution. If you implement the following navigation controller method:

```
   - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
}
```

It will give you access to the navigational controller that controls the picker, and also will send a pointer to each view controller that appears. So I believe with those two items, you can manipulate whatever you please.