# How to add photo library button on a UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, uiimagepickercontroller

Does anyone know how to enable the photo album button on a `UIImagePickerController` when it's in the camera mode?

I am very new in iOS development. I have seen this kind of question, but I can't understand it so please help me out by explaining step by step and give sample code if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023164/customizing-a-uiimagepickercontroller ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid (I looked into doing this recently) that there is no easy way (i.e no built in setting) that you can simply enable.

You must use the `cameraOverlayView` property of the `UIImagePickerController` to add a custom view over the camera view which will include a photo album button.